# Is there a way to have a client display a message when it connects to a specific AOS?

Tags: axapta

We have some old AOS instances we don't want to get rid of, but would like the clients to start moving away from.  What I'd like to do is have a box pop up whenever a client connects to one of these old AOS instances that says 'Hey, you should be using this one instead.'  I know it's possible to have a client display a message when it starts up, but is there a way to have a client display a message only when it connects to a specific AOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a *welcome message* on the **Startup message** field of the "AX Configuration Utility:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569644.aspx

You can change this message for each AOS connection that a user has.

Answer (score 1):

You could add custom code to `Application.startupPost()` to display a message if your conditions are met. You should be careful with what you add there, because it gets executed anytime a session is started, including Business Connector sessions and other situations where there may not be a client available to display the message box.